# Uncaught cannot read property data from json on button click

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm trying to pull a random String on button click from an array inside a Json File which is imported into the script.js

Most of the time it works, but sometimes when I click the button the topic isn't updated and I'm getting 2 Errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
> at HTMLButtonElement. (script.js:11:36)

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received

```
import data from "./topics.json" assert {type: 'json'};

//Button Click and Topic Change
document.getElementById("topic").innerHTML = "Test";
let topicsUsed = data
const button = document.getElementById("randomize");

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
if (topicsUsed.length == 1) resetTopics()
let topic = getTopic()
console.log("Thema = " + topic.name)
console.log("Arraylänge = " + topicsUsed.length)
topicsUsed = topicsUsed.filter(e => e !== topic)
document.getElementById("topic").innerHTML = topic.name;
document.body.style.backgroundColor = randomColor();
})

function getTopic() {
return topicsUsed[getRndInteger(0, topicsUsed.length)];
}

function resetTopics() {
topicsUsed = data;
}
```

I'm using express as a http Server, because I heard you can't just pull json data locally (I was getting some cross origin error). Do I have to use asynchronous functions because of that?

Comment: perhaps `return topicsUsed[getRndInteger(0, topicsUsed.length)]` returns `undefined` - perhaps `getRndInteger` function is poor?

Comment: `function getRndInteger(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min)
    max = Math.floor(max)
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min)
      }`

I updated getTopic() to range 1 to topicsUsed.length, the error still appears

Comment: I referenced my script.js inside my html with `<script type="module" src="script.js" async defer></script>` Maybe it has something to do with that?

Comment: Arrays in javascript start at `0` and end at `length - 1` so ... yeah, don't do that other thing ... can you verify that `topicsUsed` array is correct?

Comment: Yes that was the solution, I always forget, that I have to substract 1 from the length. Thank you!